# C error: storage size isn’t known

Tags: c

I wanna run Thimoty's Rolfe implementation of mergesort in MPI, but to get it working I need to compile this wallClock.c file that he provides.

```
#include <time.h>


double wallClock(void)
{
   struct timeval tv;
   double current;

   gettimeofday(&tv, NULL);   // Omit the timezone struct
   current = tv.tv_sec + 1.0e-06 * tv.tv_usec;

   return current;
}
```

When compiling I get the following error:

```
wallClock.c:12: error: storage size of ‘tv’ isn’t known
```

How can I fix this?

btw, I changed his `#include <sys/time.h>` to  `#include <time.h>`

it  generated the following errors

```
wallClock.c:15: error: ‘NULL’ undeclared (first use in this function)
wallClock.c:15: error: (Each undeclared identifier is reported only once
wallClock.c:15: error: for each function it appears in.)
```

I tried including stdlib.h (to fix the NULL undeclared one) and got even more obscure errors.

Comment: *"btw, I changed his `#include <sys/time.h>` to `#include <time.h>`"*...why?

Comment: @AusCBloke: Read the edited question

Comment: @omgzor That's not an obscure error. Post the "even more obscure errors".

Comment: @omgzor: `#include <sys/time.h>` and `#include <stdlib.h>` are necessary to compile that above snippet. If you have more problems, post the actual code causing the errors and the actual errors.

Comment: @cnicutar and auscbloke: can't you write a single line: #include stdlib.h on your gcc compiler? The "actual code" and "actual errors" from Rolfe's code are up there, he published the .c file exactly like that, and those are its gcc errors. I ended up discarding this and using MPI_Wtime() instead of this pointless wallClock declaration. Feel free to add #include <stdlib.h> and see how to fix those errors. Although this code no longer has practical interest to me, I will mark a working, compiling answer as accepted.

Comment: @cnicutar, thanks for not running code or your correction, really helpful. I admire your maturity.

Answer (score 21):

> btw, I changed his `#include <sys/time.h>` to `#include <time.h>`

Wrong move. [The standard](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/basedefs/sys_time.h.html) says:

> The `<sys/time.h>` header shall define the `timeval` structure, which
>   shall include at least the following members:
>
> ```
> time_t         tv_sec      Seconds. 
> suseconds_t    tv_usec     Microsecods.
> ```

#### EDIT

I took the time and compiled your code, after changing `time.h` to `sys/time.h` and adding `stdlib.h`. I got no errors. I'm using gcc version 4.6.2 20111125 on a fairly recent Linux distro.

Comment: Doesn't work. I tried that before, got more errors. That's why I switched to time.h, read the edited question please.

Comment: @omgzor Try other ways of fixing those errors. Try posting those errors for starters (perhaps in another question ?)

Comment: I think posting another question is unnecessary, the errors are posted already.

Comment: @omgzor They weren't posted when I commented. The fact that after 3 years on SO you behave this way is sad.

Comment: Sorry to offend your sensibilities cnicutar, I'll say that if you wanted to be helpful -instead of rep fishing- you could have provided a full answer, not a partial, unworking one (while asking for another question -???-). You didn't even try the code and still expect your answer to be accepted saying "oh, you should have left sys/time.h" which is insufficient to make the code above compile. Btw, I included the errors immediately after your request, you have Alzheimer's , bad reading comprehension or just wanna throw a tantrum cause your unworking answer wasn't accepted? Boo hoo.

Comment: Btw cnicutar, hahaha thanks for looking at my profile and searching for random past questions to downvote, really mature, shows you really have an important life to lead besides rep-fishing. I invite to keep looking at my old questions and downvote them all, even twice (I suspect you have a dummy account... maybe one in which you do ask questions?), that will only cost you a fraction of that big score you have. I'm impressed that you ask NO QUESTIONS, man you must be enlightened, and know everything there is to know. Kudos to you and your ginormous brain. Please downvote more. okthxbye.

Comment: @omgzor I never downvote anyone, I have no reason and nothing to gain.  I certainly have no reason to downvote you, even if you're saying I have Alzheimer's. I am sorry you feel offended by my answer, but I stand by my opinion: you do have to include that header. About the downvote part, I personally know a lot of people who look up users and downvote everything they post - I've been trying to discourage them for months.

Comment: @omgzor I edited my answer after compiling your code. I suspect it's more of a linker issue (due to MPI stuff). Please let me prove my good faith by showing me more errors so I can try to help you.

Comment: just fyi, I meet the same question as `storage size of ‘tv’ isn’t known` using `struct timeval xx` and was managed to compile it by changing from `time.h` to `sys/time.h`. I also include `<stdio.h>`. Thanks for the question and answer.

Answer (score 3):

Ideally, you should be using the modern POSIX `clock_gettime` (with `struct timespec`) instead of the now-deprecated (since 2008) `gettimeofday`. `clock_gettime` / `timespec` is also defined in `<time.h>`, so you already have everything almost right.

Comment: Thanks for teaching me about `clock_gettime()`, those are some manpages I almost never read -- but there are notes in the POSIX manpages that state _These functions are part of the Timers option and need not be available on all implementations._